# Regression in weka

Tags: weka, regression, quantifiers

I have a multiclass problem for which i want to predict the quantification using Weka (SVMs regression etc). I am a new in regression methods. So far I did regression of single class in Weka because I do not know how to provide continuous outputs for multiclass problem. Should I use individual regression model for each class? Is there any method to do simultaneous regression for each class. (my each individual class have same range of of continuous outputs...so can not differentiate if I put all four (say) class simultaneously in a .csv file as input)..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Would something like logistic regression work?  This would allow you to predict each class and not worry about continuous outputs.  It can be found in the classifiers under functions>Logistic.

Comment: Walter....Thanks for your quick reply. Let me elaborate my question more...suppose i have a four class problem whose continuous output values are in same range...(suppose within 10-50)...if i put all class data (the training data) in a single .csv file (for WEKA) with continuous outputs for each training sample...then how my regressor will tell me that the output(continuous) obtained is for which class???...I want to do simultaneous quantification of input data...